# How to run a Git command using a PowerShell script

Tags: git, powershell

How do I execute a Git command through a PowerShell script?

Answer (score 11):

Install [Git for Windows](http://git-scm.com/download/win), and make sure to put Git/bin folder in your Windows path variable.

Here is a good link to make your experience of Git and PowerShell better:

*[Make PowerShell, SSH GitHub and Git suck less on Windows](http://learnaholic.me/2012/10/12/make-powershell-and-git-suck-less-on-windows/)*